# How to display session value in JSP which is declared in interceptor?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, interceptor, ognl

I am new and testing struts2. Got value in session declared in the interceptor. Want to display session value in JSP but unable to do it.

*Anyone tell me how to do it in OGNL?*

**Interceptor**

```
package com.myapp.interceptors;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class GreetingInterceptor implements Interceptor {


    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        String Greeting = "My first Interceptor.";
        invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession().put("Greeting", Greeting);

        String result = invocation.invoke();
        return result;
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>

    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="Greeting" class="com.myapp.interceptors.GreetingInterceptor"/>
        </interceptors>

        <!-- Greeting  -->
        <action name="greet" method="Greet" class="com.myapp.actions.GreetingAction">
            <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
            <interceptor-ref name="Greeting"/>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

Comment: where is your jsp where you are trying?

Comment: I think you were missing this interceptor http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/servlet-config-interceptor.html. Whenever you are overriding interceptors Framework ignores the default stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access in your jsp as `<s:property value='#session.Greeting'/>`

Comment: you are right, but i don't think this would work for him. @Rashid please check it out, if this works.

Comment: this is the part, i'm not sure about, he doesn't have `createSession` interceptor included. maybe i'm wrong

Comment: @ashish-gupta, Your solution working. I get value displayed. Onething, Isn't there OGNL syntax like %{session.Greeting}. This EL syntax also working ${session.Greeting}. Any comments

Comment: @Jaiwo99 , that depends on its order of interceptor.

Comment: @Rashid And you EL tags as well struts supports it.